# Nav-tabs prev button on Angular Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular

my first question here.
I have a program runing on Angular 11 with Bootstrap 4.1.3. I'm trying to make a button that returns to the previous nav-tab the user was seeing, or just a button that directly goes to the previous/next tab would be ok too.
The code i'm using creates a button that does nothing on click. At this point i've tried everything i could find around the internet but nothing seem to work properly.
And also, i a beginner using Angular/Bootstrap.
So,  what i'm doind wrong? Someone can help me?

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs pl-1">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-item nav-link" (click)="exibirAba('TAB1')">TAB1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Dashboard" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-item nav-link" (click)="exibirAba('TAB2')">TAB2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Planilha" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-item nav-link" (click)="exibirAba('TAB3')">TAB3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Back</a>
```

```
    $('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
     const prevTabLinkEl = $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').prev('li').find('a')[0];
     const prevTab = new bootstrap.Tab(prevTabLinkEl);
     prevTab.show();
    });
```

Comment: Why jquery with Angular? You should ditch jquery if you are working with Angular. Also do you need a multistep functionality, like surveys? There are npm packages for that, if so I will search the name for you.

Comment: i have tabs like this: [Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/d7X3s15VCS) (not my code, just example)
But i want the button to go to the previous tab the user was seeing, even if it was not the direct next/previous. E.g.: i am in the tab1, go to the tab3, so if i click this "return" button, it will send me back to the tab 1.